# Azure Workbook parameter for resource and resource group

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I've been defeated by Kusto on what I thought to be a simple query...
I'm making my first workbook and playing with parameters. I can list and select a Resource Group, but I can't make the following parameter (Virtual Machines) populate with the VMs when more than one Resource Group is selected. The `ResourceGroup` passes a comma delineated string of the group names as a property `resourcegroup` just fine. I cannot figure out how to translate that string into a usable where-statement. My query works just fine when I manually string several Resource Groups together so I assume I'm getting burned by my understanding of `let` and arrays in Kusto. If there is a better way of doing what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

```
//This will work so long as 1 Resource Group is passed from the previous parameter
resources
| where resourceGroup in ('{ResourceGroup:resourcegroup}') and type =~ microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| project value = id , label = name
```

I've figured out I can get a proper array with `split('{ResourceGroup:resourcegroup}',",")`, but, again, I haven't been able to marry up that object with a where-statement.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in https://github.com/microsoft/Application-Insights-Workbooks/blob/master/Documentation/Parameters/DropDown.md#special-casing-all

NORMALLY there is a way to do this:

```
let resourceGroups = dynamic([{ResourceGroup:resourcegroup}]);// turns even an empty string into a valid array

resources
| where (array_length(resourceGroups)==0 // allows 0 length array to be "all"
or resourceGroup in (resourceGroups)) // or filters to only those in the set
 and type =~ microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| project value = id , label = name
```

however, i don't think Azure Resource Graph allows using `let` this way?

if you get an error that `let` isn't allowed, you'll have to do that dynamic thing inline a couple times instead:

```
resources
| where (array_length(dynamic([{ResourceGroup:resourcegroup}]))==0 // allows 0 length array to be "all"
or resourceGroup in (dynamic([{ResourceGroup:resourcegroup}]))) // or filters to only those in the set
 and type =~ microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| project value = id , label = name
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the easiest way to achieve just that - filtering by the resource group param:

`| where iff(resourceGroup =~ '{ResourceGroup:resourcegroup}', true, false)`

It seems to be some issue with the types, and without the iif function it doesn't seem to consider the result as bool.